# Windows Phone ToastNotification cancellation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I created toast notifications by instructions from this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631260.aspx

By clicking on notification it is cancelled and removed from action center.
**Is there any way not to remove notification by clicking on it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains how to control the behaviour for all messages in the action center:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631260.aspx

What you could do is sending the toast again and suppress the popup:

```
toast.SuppressPopup = true;
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```